# @Inject and @Resource remove in Spring Boot 3.2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wanted to practice using annotations in SpringBoot 3.2.2, but when introducing these annotations, I don't have the option to import these annotations. Unless they were removed in SpringBoot 3.2.2. In the documentation dated December 23, 2023, it was mentioned that it is not recommended to use.

Comment: yeah thats right

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel you cannot remove something from a framework that was never part of it in the first place.

Comment: its also not recommended to use something that isnt in the framework, although i doubt theyd mention that

Comment: Instead of `Inject` use `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired` The `Resource` is available as `jakarta.annotation.Resource`

Comment: @NicoVanBelle , it turns out that these annotations were not part of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Inject` and `@Resource` annotations are part of the Java EE specification. They have little to do with the Spring framework. However, since they are a Java standard, Spring supports them as well. But because Spring has their own specialized annotations that provide more options, they advice users to use their annotations instead.

So where are these annotations now? It's actually not the Spring version that answers this question but the Java distribution. Because these `JSR-330` and `JSR-250` annotations were part of the `javax` package, they could not simply be moved to other Open Source Java distributions due to issues with the Oracle licensing. So the annotations are now part of a separate dependency (Jakarta) that you can include in any project.

For `@Inject`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For `@Resource`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/standard-annotations.html

also

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations.html
(read note at the bottom)